# Is firebase server timestamp value same all over the world?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build a chat application, where users can send and receive text messages. Each message has a timestamp field which stores the time in milliseconds when the message was sent.

For receiving messages I first fetch the timestamp of the last message in my local room database and then query database for all messages whose timestamp is greater than that of last message on device (this part is just to reduce number of read requests).

In order to achieve this I need to ensure that all messages have a timestamp belonging to a fixed timezone. Right now I am using the [clock skew](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#clock-skew) value to get the current server time using device local time.

```kotlin
val offsetRef = Firebase.database.getReference(".info/serverTimeOffset")
offsetRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val offset = snapshot.getValue(Double::class.java) ?: 0.0
        val estimatedServerTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis() + offset
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Listener was cancelled")
    }
})
```

So, if multiple clients fetch current server time at the same instant, will they receive the same value or will that value correspond to their local timezone only?
And, if the returned value is of the local timezone, is there some way to convert it to (say) UTC time?

[I am using a combination of Room database and Firestore for saving data, and using Realtime database just to calculate current server time using clock skew value.]

Comment: Firestore timestamps don't have a timezone. They are all represented in UTC (offset in unix epoch time), which is standard for all computers.  Timezone only matters when it's time to render a time relevant to someone who declares an offset from UTC.  Obviously, this TZ will be different depending on the user.

Comment: @Arpit Does this firebase function has any limit of free usage?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding to your question,

A timestamp is a point which is independent of any time zone or calendar.

So what you need to do is, fetch the UTC timestamp and convert it to local time as per country or timezone.

For example:

> UTC timestamp is "1631113200". Considering it to be a string value

Using the below extension function:

```
fun String.toLocalTimestamp(): LocalDateTime? {
        val epochValue = this.toLong()
        return Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochValue).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime()
}
```

Returns:

> 1970-01-19T21:05:13.200

Comment: My question was on how to get that UTC timestamp. Does firebase server time represent UTC timestamp value?

Comment: Firestore timestamp is un UTC format, and do not store timezone. Its same whoever wants to read that. True time value will be shown as per the conversion method shown above.